# InAppBrowser view doesn't match with actual browser view in ios

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I am using inappbrowser to open external link in my project for ios. But the external link has horizontal scroll in "inappbrowser" , when i am opening the link in system browser ,it is opening fine. Is there any way so that i can get the external link view without scroll in inappbrowser. I am using cordova 2.8.0.
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Could you write the code you are using?

Comment: Cordova 2.8.0 is very old, regardless of other issues you could consider upgrading to the latest 6.1.1 version.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options that you can customize your view.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#cordovainappbrowseropen

I dont understand if the problem is that the webview is not correctly zoomed, or you want do disable the horizontal scroll, but check this two options:

`enableViewportScale` and `disallowoverscroll`

Answer (score 0):

The server that you are opening the link to may be looking for specific user agent matches to serve a mobile page template, hard to say without more detail.  If that's the case, then you can override the In App Browser's user agent with a string of your choice (e.g. to match whatever the server might be expecting in order to make it render a "mobile" page).

To use this you'll need to get Cordova upgraded to something newer than 2.8 which I would recommend doing in any case, then look at the "OverrideUserAgent" setting, example from [the docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/platforms/ios/config.html#iOS%20Configuration):

```
<preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="Mozilla/5.0 My Browser" />
```